# 2 elements in same row office ui fabric

Tags: office-ui-fabric

How do I show 2 elements on the same row? I have a UI as shown below:
[image]
I need to show both elements on the same row as shown below:
[image]
Here is my code:

```
<div>     
<Dropdown           
    options={[
        { key: 'A', text: 'Option a' },
        { key: 'B', text: 'Option b' },
    ]}
/>  
</div>
<IconButton
iconProps={{ iconName: "add" }}
title={"Add"}
className={styles.rightButton}
onClick={this.addClicked}
/>
```

and styles.rightButton has:

```
.rightButton {
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
 }
```

Please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved by applying `display: flex` to a *container* as demonstrated below:

```
const dropDownStyles = {
  root: {
    width: "240px"
  }
};

export default class DropdownExample extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div style={{display:'flex'}}>
        <Dropdown
          styles={dropDownStyles}
          options={[
            { key: "A", text: "Option a" },
            { key: "B", text: "Option b" }
          ]}
        />
        <IconButton iconProps={{ iconName: "add" }} title={"Add"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[**Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/mz77p0nr3j)

**References**

[Aligning Items in a Flex Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)